# Heroku: Dockerized Rails API Deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, docker

I have this Rails 4 API which is using Postgresql, Sidekiq (and therefore Redis) and Puma server.

I need to deploy it to Heroku and I deployed it successfully following the oficcial [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). However first I don't know why it was telling me that there was no web process running.

```
2010-10-06T21:51:37-07:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd=17.17.17.17 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

So I had to turn ON dyno manually.

And since that heroku logs just keep telling me that App crashed

```
2010-10-06T21:51:12-07:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd=17.17.17.17 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What I did before due to other tutorials is:

Set up `config/puma.rb` file

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Set up `Procfile`

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Set up `app.json`

```
{
  "name": "Cool name",
  "description": "Really meaningful description",
  "image": "heroku/ruby",
  "addons": [
    "heroku-postgresql"
  ]
}
```

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
web:
  build: .
  command: puma
  ports:
    - "9292:9292"
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/app_name
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true

sidekiq:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/app_name
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  env_file:
    - .env
db:
  image: postgres

redis:
  image: redis
```

`.env` file

```
REDIS_HOST=redis://redis:6379/0
```

So could anyone tell me what is wronf with my setup for it deployed successfuly to Heroku but can't run there anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Heroku's container-based approach does not match cleanly with the Docker Compose workflow.

What does your Dockerfile look like? When deploying using Docker, the Procfile is not used at all, so you have to have add the start command using `CMD` in your Dockerfile.

```
CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

This also means that for running Sidekiq, you need to build a separate Docker image with a different `CMD`. You need a second Dockerfile in another (sub-)directory in order to accomplish that with Heroku's CLI.

Comment: Sorry, I can't try your answer for now. But anyway your help is really appreciated so I upvoted your answer. Thank you!